# Email validation function cannot insert inside the cs file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a regex email validation function that i have take it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) .But the problem is when i insert it to my cs file then it shows me the errors.( it shows me lots of erors like  unexpected / , ] expected,; expected )

Code

```
function ValidateEmail(email) {
                        var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
                        return expr.test(email);
                    }
```

In here i have paste the screenshots also,
[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend you use the `[EmailAddress]` attribute on your property instead (which will correctly validate the property on both the client and the server) using a correct regular expression

Comment: try `@Html.Raw("/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/");`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to use `@` in JS but it's recognized as a Razor expression - you see that Razor colored it yellow? you need to escape it. e.g. use `@@` so Razor would understand you're not writing a Razor expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use that regex in C# if yes try it like this:

[[IdeOne Demo]](http://ideone.com/JSAhzB)

```
string email = "an.email@ahost.com";
string regex = @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";

Regex rgx = new Regex(regex);

Boolean result = rgx.IsMatch(email);
```